# How to parse data from a website using Jsoup in android

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I am developing an application in which I want some data from a website to display in activity. For this I'm using Jsoup to parse data. But I am getting error at:

`org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

Here it is my complete code below, I am not getting any idea about what is wrong I'm doing...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract.Document;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Events extends Activity 
{
    //WebView web1;
    TextView t1;
    String url="https://sites.google.com/site/holyfamilychurchpestomsagar/notices-for-the-week";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Title t2=new Title();
        t2.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.events, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Elements title;
        String desc;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title
                title = document.select("meta[name=title]");
                desc = title.attr("content");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // Set title into TextView
            t1.setText(desc);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is the device online? Ok, im sure you thought of that ;-)   Are you
>   sure its exactly this line?   Are you running in your catch clause, or
>   does the app crash?
>
> You should always add a null pointer check when working with jsoup,
>   because when the selecting process is unsuccessful, the method will
>   return null!
>
> Can you post your stacktrace?

Ok when the app crashes then Im pretty shure its not the connection itself but one of the lines below. Add a check for null pointers, or add a catch clause.